# Youtube API Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 403

Tags: javascript, vue.js, youtube-api

I am attempting to integrate the YouTube API into a new Vuejs application and I am testing it in the browser and continuing to get a 404 error.

I did have a `www` missing, but I continue to get this same error when I make the request. Is there something I am not seeing in my code that is wrong? Is it a cors issue? If so, what is the standard practice for resolving this in Vuejs? I have made a similar application in Reactjs and did not run into this issue.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <SearchBar @termChange="onTermChange"></SearchBar>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import SearchBar from "./components/SearchBar";
const API_KEY = "<api_key>";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    SearchBar
  },
  methods: {
    onTermChange(searchTerm) {
      axios
        .get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search", {
          params: {
            keys: API_KEY,
            type: "video",
            part: "snippet",
            q: searchTerm
          }
        })
        .then(response => console.log(response));
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I did notice in the response I got this message:

```
"code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

I am not sure what this means.

Comment: Are you sure `keys` is how you authenticate your app? It doesn't appear in [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps)

Comment: @Phil, you nailed it. It's not `keys`, its `key`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

This means that you have exceeded your limit to serve videos from youtube.
You need to create an account to be able to show more videos.

If you're sure you haven't exceeded your limit/ have an account double check your developer console that the API is turned on.
[Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis).

What I would suggest is to add a `catch` to your call to handle errors in the future.

```
axios
  .get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search", {
    params: {
      keys: API_KEY,
      type: "video",
      part: "snippet",
      q: searchTerm
    }
  })
  .then(response => console.log(response));
  .catch(err => { console.log(err); }
```

Answer (score 3):

Put your Api key in url like

"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=YOUR_API_KEY"

```
axios.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=Your_Api_Key", {
          params: {
            type: "video",
            part: "snippet",
            q: searchTerm
          }
        })
        .then(response => console.log(response));
```

You will find an example as well [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started)

Comment: Axios `params` are URL query parameters already. Are you saying OP should use `key` instead of `keys`?

Comment: @Phil, remove keys from the request at all and just add the key to the URL

Comment: You could also have just set `key: API_KEY` in the `params` object

Comment: @Phil, you nailed it, I had `keys: API_KEY` instead of `key: API_KEY`. It works now. Go ahead and add that as an answer if you like.

Comment: Nice find on the documentation example! Also, I think you may have misunderstood what I meant about the `params`; everything in the `params` object goes into the URL query string

Comment: here you will find an examples 

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests

Comment: @Daniel no, I didn't. But mooga definitely did. You should accept this answer

Comment: @Phil may be you are right as a concept  i got you know `Params` will be added auto. to the url but Google expect it from the URL

Comment: @Phil, not a problem if you don't want to post as an answer, but it was your redirecting me to look at `keys` that I realized, I meant to write `key`. I tried it and I am back to work. Thank you.

Comment: @mooga again, Axios **will** put all the `params` into the URL before the request is made. It's a convenience utility as it will also make sure each param key and value is URL encoded

Answer (score 0):

for some users, this error might be because of cause sanctions. so try to run your project using a DNS or VPN.

Answer (score -1):

Solved this by configure/updating/enabling the settings.

The api key worked in the past for me. When returning to use it again, i received a 403 error.

The server understood my request, but denied me access to the info.

Just go into developers console, go to enable apis, search youtube, and enable it, your key will now work as expected.

[image]